# Run katz centrality function in a list of igraph objects

Tags: r, lapply, igraph, eigenvalue, node-centrality

I'm trying to run *katzcent* function for a list of igraph interaction matrices, but a *invalid alpha value* error keeps appearing

```
# creating a list of random matrices and naming rows and columns

rmat <- lapply(1:162, function(x) matrix(rbinom(300, 1, 0.5),
                                        nrow=20, ncol=15))

coln <- lapply(rmat, function(x) {colnames(x) <- letters[1:15]; x})

mats <- lapply(coln, function(x) {rownames(x) <- letters[1:20]; x})

library(igraph)
library(centiserve)

# creating list of igraph objects from my incidence matrices

list_ig <- lapply(mats,igraph::graph_from_incidence_matrix)

kat <- lapply(list_ig, FUN=katzcent)
```

*Error: Invalid alpha value* keep appearing.
I can use *alpha = 0.1*, that is the default for this function, so I don't need to modify that.

When running the *katscent* by single networks it work for some networks and for others give the same error

```
katzcent(list_ig[[1]])
```

Does anyone that is familiar with this function in centiserve package have a clue why this is hapenning?